# How can I maintain ssh connection from my Windows laptop to Ubuntu desktop

Tags: display, cygwin

I need to ssh from Windows laptop to my Ubuntu desktop.
So at work I in cygwin , I ssh to Ubuntu desktop.
But at home, I need to login to VPN and I need to re-ssh to ubuntu desktop.

And some times at home, I suspend my laptop and lost my VPN connection and I need to relogin VPN.

My question is does screen allow me to maintain my ssh connection after my connection is disconnected and I need to manually connected?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for marking as the answer! Feel free to Up-Vote as well, if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does! It's what I use (as described on my [blog post](http://www.talk-about-it.ca/?p=57) about it), and it goes between different connections: different SSH, Telnet (if I was brave!), or the console!

Start it with the plain old `screen` command, then start your work. If you get disconnected, oh well! When you re-establish connection (via SSH, I assume), run `screen -r` as the same user, and you're instantly connected!

Comment: It does not work for me. on my laptop, I VPN to work. In cygwin shell, I ssh to my work laptop. I disconnect VPN. The shell said 'Write faield. Connection reset by peer'. And I reconnect VPN, at this time, i go back to cygwin shell and type 'screen -r' It said 'There is a screen on 5333.pty0.LTREA-MIKE (Attached) There is no screen to be resumed'. I

Comment: Are you using the plain "screen" command once you connect via ssh?

Comment: Do you mean i need to do 'screen' on my laptop and then 'screen' on my  remote desktop after I connect it via ssh? I am confused where should I run 'screen' and 'screen -r'?

Comment: Run the commands on the remote server. Screen starts the session. When you need to reconnect, log in to the server, and run screen -r to reconnect